# Read file content from server to batch variable

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, passwords, scp

My client I use is a Windows 10 Pro. My server is an Ubuntu server.

On my Ubuntu server, there is a file called `password.txt`. Right now, in my batch file I am executing, I download this file via `scp ferit@192.168.2.7:~/password.txt C:\Temp` and perform other tasks in the batch file by reading the content of password.txt and deleting the password.txt with `sdelete64` once my operations are done.

However, the downloading and reading the password-content from the file isn't really what I want to have. Is there any chance that I can `echo` or `cat` the content of `password.txt` into a variable in my batch file and use it there without downloading it from the server?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: *Is there any chance that I can echo or cat the content of password.txt into a variable in my batch file and use it there without downloading it from the server?* For `echo` or `cat` or something else you must get the file content from the server previously, is it?

Comment: @Akina true. That's why I'm asking if there is any way - I don't mind how - to get the content from the 
password.txt on the server directly to a batch variable without downloading it.

Comment: So the file body MUST be retieved before any operation with it. Dixi.